# Robomongo - How to export aggregation results to a csv file

Tags: python, mongodb, robo3t

I have a complex aggregation query in robomongo and I wanna export the results of the query to csv file. Is this doable? How can I do it?

I know that this other software Studio3T have that function but it's not free. It has a community version and it warns you about not using it for commercial use. and my project enables me to make some money so I thought I can't use the community version. I'm trying to find a way to export that results from robomongo. Does anyone know how to do this?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a free solution in Robo 3T.

1. Take the raw JSON output.
2. Use any online **JSON to CSV** converter

I took the first link in Google and it worked on [this website](https://json-csv.com/)

Comment: It works fine, but Robo 3T limits the result to 50 documents

Comment: You will be able to see more than 50 documents if you use the 'DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 500;' command as described in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47459320/934383

Answer (score -4):

This is the best you can do..

[image: Screen shot - Robomongo]

The panel on the right hand corner - shift it to "view results in text mode", then select all and copy .. you will have to paste it in a new .csv file.

This is the best you can do for there is no export csv in robomongo

Comment: Does copying and pasting the JSON record to a CSV file will help converting the file to CSV ?