# RoboMongo: Doesn't display all documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, robo3t

When I open a collection, it only displays the first 50 documents rather then all of them. How do I make it so that RoboMongo display all documents in the collection (preferably automatically)?

[robomongo result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5fn8.png)

Comment: *Unrelated to your problem* MongoDb company has created a free to use tool to look and manipulate database data. [mongodb-compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass).

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT that tool doesn't allow you to change the batch size of returned documents, so is not a viable alternative to solve this problem

Comment: @camslice mongodb-compass offers you a full pagination of what's in the collections. So the problem does not apply at all.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT RoboMongo (or Robo 3T) also offers full pagination, with its default batch size being 50. You can change this size to whatever you like via the config file (see answers below). However mongodb-compass has a default batch size of 20 which you can't change via a config file or through any app settings. The question does not ask for "full pagination" it asks to see "all of [the documents]".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**UPDATE 06 december 2019**: The initial solution is not working from the v1.3.1 of Robomongo. If you enter 0, Robomongo will throw an error. See the **EDIT 1** for new solution.

There is an input at the upper right which gives you the possiblity to change the number of displayed documents, just under the query. Change it to 0 and press Enter. It'll load all documents.

[image: The input buttons]

Even if the 50 reappears after, you have all documents displayed.

**EDIT 1**: The above seems to be fixed in the newer releases (from v1.3.1).

As suggested by @learnsomemore in the comments, you can add `DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 500;` before your query to change the returned array size.

This was originaly given in [a comment by @davidm06 in the GitHub issue "Aggregate only shows 50 results #1157" from the RoboMongo public repository](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1157#issuecomment-345234270).

Comment: maybe they thought this was a bug and fixed it, it throws an error that it must be greater than 0 in v1.3.1. If i make it more than 50, it still doesn't give me more than 50.

Comment: I did not test recently, maybe this is fixed! :)

Comment: I just saw this on their github issues thread. Please update your answer to include this which i tested works. https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1157#issuecomment-345234270
 Just add this above the query `DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 500;`

Comment: This worked but led to my local timezone being set to some random timezone

Comment: Using version 1.4.3, neither of these fixes works

Answer (score 19):

You can also use [toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) at the end to get the whole result at once.

[image: example toArray()]

Answer (score 15):

You can change the default batch size:

- Edit `robomongo.json` (in `~/.config/robomongo/<version>/` on Linux/MacOS, in `c:\Users\YourName\.config\<version>/` on Windows)
- Change the `batchSize` attribute, you can choose a value of fixed size (e.g. `100`) or choose `0` to mean "all documents" (h/t to @PaulRey though I've had mixed results in using this symbolic, see comments below this question):

  ```
  {
    "batchSize" : 100,
    ...
  }
  ```
- Save `robomongo.json` and restart RoboMongo

This allows you to increase the default batch size albeit at the potential cost of waiting longer for results.

More details [in the docs](http://blog.robomongo.org/whats-new-in-robomongo-0-8-1/).

Comment: You can set the value 0 which is apparently interprated as "all" documents. It works in the UI.

Comment: @PaulRey Thanks, though in an earlier verison of my answer I actually suggested `0` as the symbolic which means: "all documents" and then I tested by setting `batchSize: 0` in robomongo.json (on Robomongo 0.9.0-RC3) and got mixed results so I edited my answer to remove that suggestion.

Comment: Can confirm this still works on version 1.3.1, however the location and name of the JSON file have changed over time: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/wiki/Robomongo-Config-File-Guide

For v1.3.1 it's: `.3T/robo-3t/1.3.1/robo3t.json`

Comment: This did not work for me, when I set the value in the json and restarted the program, it was set back to 50...

Comment: @craastad You have to stop Robo 3T before editing `robo3t.json`, then edit your configuration, save, and after that, you can restart the program.

Answer (score 0):

go to terminal and execute:

DBQuery.shellBatchSize = {desired number};

Example:

DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 90;